# JS Open tab in background / simulate ctrl-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, tabs, mouseevent

I am trying to open a tab in the background on a button click similar to the way `ctrl-click` works.  I've tried simulating a `ctrl-click` in the following way, it manages to open in a new tab but it doesn't open in the background.  It switches to the new tab instead.  This doesn't work for me as the process on this tab takes a little bit to run and I don't want my users staring at a blank tab that long.

Here's what I've tried:

**Simulate Ctrl-Click:**

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'http://www.google.com';
var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, false, 0, null);
a.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

This opens up a new tab and changes focus to the new tab even tho the ctrlKey option is set to true.

**Change Window Focus**

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'http://www.google.com';
var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, false, 0, null);
a.dispatchEvent(evt);
window.focus();
```

Works the same way as above.

How do I get this to open completely in the background without ever switching tabs?

Comment: have you find a solution?

Comment: It really feels like it would be almost impossible to think of a case where you need that without malicious intent...

Comment: @BojidarStanchev I'm just trying to avoid the tab openning, they would still see the download happen.  Many sites do this where you click download and then just see a download start without switching tabs or pages.

Answer (score -1):

In pure javascript, you can use the [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent) for that:

```
const a = document.createElement("a");
a.setAttribute("href", "https://www.google.com/");
a.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", {ctrlKey: true}));
```

Comment: This may have worked at some point. Now it does not!