# JS open url in new tab on background is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, window

I want script to open in new tab url without focusing on it. I
tried:

```
window.open("https://www.google.com/").blur();
window.focus();
```

But it opens a new tab and focuses on google.com not on site with script. What's wrong?

edit:

This [Open a new tab in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background) is not resolving my question. Answer is too old and doesn't work anymore! Admins please read bold text: `UPDATE: By version 41 of Google Chrome, initMouseEvent seemed to have a changed behavior, and so this answer no longer works.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS open url in new tab on background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72748311/js-open-url-in-new-tab-on-background)

Comment: @Christopher of course not. It's mine question but it was blocked with reason `This question already has answers here:` as I wrote that answer is too old and it's not working anymore. I edited answer but I cannot wait admins to recheck questions.

Comment: If you think your question was closed inappropriately you should explain why and request that it be reopened.

Comment: There are also other [unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819883/js-open-tab-in-background-simulate-ctrl-click) related to this topic. Some sites abused this to load other sites in the background with stuff like "Hey you are the 1.000.000th Visitor! Congrats on your new bagpipe!". And there might also be some other reasons why this behavior was changed. - If you think it is a bug, you can create a new issue at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list for Chromium based Browsers or https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/ for Firefox.

Comment: @dippas no. I've mentioned it in my question.

Comment: The so called popunder-methods are security related issues and if a new one gets discovered, it won't be available for long. – Some related issues: https://crbug.com/229402, https://crbug.com/304547, https://crbug.com/521343, https://crbug.com/752824, https://crbug.com/833148, https://crbug.com/836841, https://crbug.com/1058737